# Running multiple SQL queries is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run multiple queries in 1 php:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table1 SET column='1' WHERE id='1'";
$sql.= "INSERT INTO table2(column1, column2) VALUES ('1', '2')";
if (!$mysqli->multi_query($link, $sql)) {
```

When I run this I get a error. Does anybody know what is wrong with my script?

Here is my full script:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");                   
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "UPDATE table1 SET column='1' WHERE id='1'";
$sql.= "INSERT INTO table2(column1, column2) VALUES ('1', '2')";
if (!$mysqli->multi_query($link, $sql)) {

echo "Success";
} else {
 echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

**Edit 1:**

I get the following error:
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in ......../script.php on line 24

Fatal error: Call to a member function multi_query() on a non-object in ......../script.php on line 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by replacing:

```
if (!$mysqli->multi_query($link, $sql)) {
```

With:

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($link,$sql)) {
```

Comment: Great.  Now stop using the multi-query option.  It is a tremendous security risk, particularly with queries built with string concatenation, which you should also never do.  Forget this option exists.  Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

You need to end one statement with a semicolon and then put a space before starting the next

```
$sql = "UPDATE table1 SET column='1' WHERE id='1'; ";
```

Also, you're using the object oriented function instead of the procedural. So change it to this

```
if (!$mysqli_multi_query($link, $sql)) {
```

Comment: Doesnt changed anything, I still have the same error. See Edit 1 in my first post for the error